# Allowing blocked IP to view 403 ErrorDocument

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, errordocument

I have a script that is automatically adding IP addresses to my.htaccess file based on lookups in spam databases.  However, I would like for subsequent visits from those addresses to be able to view a 403 ErrorDocument I create.  Obviously, though, they cannot, as they have been denied.  My .htaccess looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

deny from <ip address>
deny from <ip address>
deny from <ip address>
deny from <ip address>
yada yada yada
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I am adding the addresses via PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Denied requests get a 403 error, if the 403 ErrorDocument is not properly configured (as yours *might* be), there additionally is a 500 internal server error.

Comment: How can I configure things so that my 403 is still served, even if the users are denied? It's a chicken/egg thing right now :)  See some of the posts below, specifically my response to Sean.

Comment: Just configure your 403 error document properly. Add you own IP to the denies temporarily and test. Normally it's not problem to use a php file for that.

Comment: How should it be configured? Sorry if I'm being obtuse...

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two way:

1. ErrorDocument 403 http://www.yourdomain.com/403.php
2. ErrorDocument 403 "Go and Do NOT return!"

of course, First one will redirect user!
If you have particular file formats on your site(like .php,.txt,.xml,.htm,...) you can use this one but I DO NOT recommend it!

```
<Files ~ "\.(inc|sql|.php|.html)$">
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
  deny from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

---

Update:
As `Sean Kimball` mentioned you can use rewrite mod (of course it's possible,it's Apache)

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}  ^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule (.*)  403.php
```

Comment: I think that I will have to use your second suggestion, as the first results in a 403 error while retrieving the 403 document :)  Edit for your edit:  See my response to Sean's response.

Comment: ErrorDocument 403 "Go and Do NOT return!"   This works for me! I just need to display a simple message :)

Answer (score 0):

I would think a rewrite rule would be more appropriate - though I'm not 100% sure you  can redirect based on an ip address. You would need to check the mod_rewrite docs.

Comment: I tried this initially, but you can't easily insert into a document with php. I would have to read in the entire file into an array, add the new entry in the middle, so that the redirect line doesn't get overwritten.  If you know of some other way of easily doing this, I'm all ears (or...eyes...) :)